Optimising greedy algo to search for matching lines across files
currently I have this below code:
import os
from collections import defaultdict
import re

# Parameters
X_percent = 0.93  # Desired coverage percentage (e.g., 93%)
lambda_penalty = 500  # Adjusted penalty
max_attack_time = 3600  # Maximum allowed execution time per attack in seconds
max_total_time = 20 * 3600  # Maximum total execution time in seconds (15 hours)
min_new_plains = 10  # Minimum number of new plains an attack must cover
max_plain_weight = 5  # Maximum weight assigned to any plain
set_a_directory = '/root/setA/'  # Directory containing Set A files
file_b_path = '/root/h.txt'  # Path to File B

# Step 1: Read File B and assign unique IDs to plains
plain_to_id = {}
id_to_plain = {}
with open(file_b_path, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        plain = line.strip()
        if plain not in plain_to_id:
            plain_id = len(plain_to_id)
            plain_to_id[plain] = plain_id
            id_to_plain[plain_id] = plain

total_plains = len(plain_to_id)
print(f"Total number of plains in File B: {total_plains}")

# Step 2: Process Set A files and build data structures
attack_info = []
plain_to_attacks = defaultdict(set)  # Maps plain ID to set of attack indices

# Regular expression to extract time from file name
time_pattern = re.compile(r'^(\d+)_')

# Iterate over each file in Set A
for file_name in os.listdir(set_a_directory):
    file_path = os.path.join(set_a_directory, file_name)
    
    # Extract execution time from file name
    time_match = time_pattern.match(file_name)
    if not time_match:
        continue  # Skip files that don't match the pattern
    execution_time = int(time_match.group(1))
    
    if execution_time > max_attack_time:
        continue  # Exclude attacks over the maximum allowed time
    
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        if not lines:
            continue  # Skip empty files
        attack_command = lines[0].strip()
        plains_covered = set()
        
        for line in lines[1:]:
            parts = line.strip().split(':')
            if not parts:
                continue
            plain = parts[0].strip()
            if plain in plain_to_id:
                plain_id = plain_to_id[plain]
                plains_covered.add(plain_id)
                plain_to_attacks[plain_id].add(len(attack_info))  # Index of this attack
        
        attack_info.append({
            'command': attack_command,
            'time': execution_time,
            'plains': plains_covered,
            'index': len(attack_info)
        })

num_attacks = len(attack_info)
print(f"Total number of attacks in Set A after filtering: {num_attacks}")

# Step 3: Compute the number of attacks covering each plain (f_p)
plain_cover_count = {}
for plain_id in plain_to_id.values():
    cover_count = len(plain_to_attacks[plain_id])
    plain_cover_count[plain_id] = cover_count

# Step 4: Assign weights to plains with a maximum weight
plain_weights = {}
for plain_id, f_p in plain_cover_count.items():
    if f_p > 0:
        plain_weights[plain_id] = min(1.0 / f_p, max_plain_weight)
    else:
        plain_weights[plain_id] = max_plain_weight

# Step 5: Implement the weighted greedy algorithm with adjusted efficiency
total_plains_needed = int(total_plains * X_percent)
print(f"Number of plains needed for {X_percent*100}% coverage: {total_plains_needed}")

covered_plains = set()
selected_attacks = []
remaining_attacks = set(range(num_attacks))
total_execution_time = 0

while len(covered_plains) < total_plains_needed and remaining_attacks:
    best_efficiency = -1
    best_attack = None

    for i in remaining_attacks:
        attack = attack_info[i]
        new_plains = attack['plains'] - covered_plains
        if len(new_plains) < min_new_plains:
            continue  # Skip attacks that cover too few new plains
        # Calculate W_i (sum of weights of new plains)
        W_i = sum(plain_weights[p] for p in new_plains)
        # Adjusted Efficiency E_i
        efficiency = (W_i * len(new_plains)) / (attack['time'] + lambda_penalty)
        if efficiency > best_efficiency:
            best_efficiency = efficiency
            best_attack = i

    if best_attack is None:
        print("No further attacks can improve coverage.")
        break

    # Check if adding this attack exceeds the maximum total execution time
    if total_execution_time + attack_info[best_attack]['time'] > max_total_time:
        print("Reached maximum total execution time limit.")
        break

    # Select the attack with the highest adjusted efficiency
    selected_attacks.append(best_attack)
    covered_plains.update(attack_info[best_attack]['plains'])
    remaining_attacks.remove(best_attack)
    total_execution_time += attack_info[best_attack]['time']

    # Optional: Print progress
    coverage_percentage = (len(covered_plains) / total_plains) * 100
    print(f"Selected attack {best_attack}: Coverage {coverage_percentage:.2f}%, "
          f"Total Time: {total_execution_time / 3600:.2f} hours")

# Step 6: Output the results
print("\nSelected Attacks:")
for idx in selected_attacks:
    attack = attack_info[idx]
    print(f"Attack Index: {idx}")
    print(f"Command: {attack['command']}")
    print(f"Time: {attack['time']} seconds")
    print(f"Plains Covered: {len(attack['plains'])}")
    print("-----------------------------")

final_coverage = (len(covered_plains) / total_plains) * 100
print(f"Final Coverage: {final_coverage:.2f}%")
print(f"Total Execution Time: {total_execution_time / 3600:.2f} hours")
print(f"Total Attacks Selected: {len(selected_attacks)}")

I have a directory of files, we will call this Set A files. Each file has a runtime as the file name follow by _Randstring.txt, The first line in each file is a command/attack and the rest of the lines are 2 columns seperated by ":" that are produced by that command/attack(the result of another program), the left side is what we can call plains, the right side can be ignored. I have another file seperate we can call file B. This has 121k lines of plains. My goal with this python program is to find commands/attack chains thats files plains match a certain percentage of plains in file B in the shortest time possible. The plains in Set A files have a lot of overlap and I have 3600 files with a total of 250million lines, so time/computation is an issue hence the greedy algo. Currently my python code isn't producing the best results, its choosing too many attack chains and too high run time. Is there any way I can make this better so the attack chain it chooses is more "optimal", I don't mind waiting a few hours and have 192core 256gb PC. Thanks
